# When using str_match, how to get output matrix column without the starting string?

Tags: r, string, extract

I am using str_match in R to extract values between start and end strings. For example, my code looks like this:

`str_match("xxxxxBeginning Middle Endxxxxxxxx","(Beginning.+?)End")[,2]`

This currently outputs **Beginning Middle**. How do I get an output of just **Middle** alone, without **Beginning**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the brackets around the part you want to extract.

```
stringr::str_match("xxxxxBeginning Middle Endxxxxxxxx","Beginning (.+?) End")[,2]
#[1] "Middle"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use a regex lookaround

```
str_match("xxxxxBeginning Middle Endxxxxxxxx","(?<=Beginning ).*(?= End)")[,1]
[1] "Middle"
```